# The gateway did not receive a response from 'Microsoft.DataFactory' within the specified time period

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-git-deployment, azure-adf

I am trying to configure git (github) for my existing data factory. I am getting this error:

> The gateway did not receive a response from 'Microsoft.DataFactory' within the specified time period.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been having a variety of problems all day with a Data Factory that is linked to a DevOps repository. In the last few minutes, I've been getting the error message above when the Publish process tries to generate the ARM template after publishing.

I am about to report the issue to Microsoft.

Comment: Thank you @Kevin

Comment: Please let me know the response you get from Microsoft.

Comment: If you go to https://status.azure.com/en-us/status you will see an issue that looks like it impacts Cosmos DBs, but it also impacts Data Factories. below is the update we received 10 minutes ago:

Comment: Current Status: We have narrowed down our investigation to a Cosmos DB related issue, which is a dependent service for Azure Data Factory V2. We are performing two parallel mitigation workstreams in attempt to recover the service:

. . .


As mitigation workstreams continue, we will provide updates as these workstreams complete, status of the event changes or when any mitigation ETA can be confirmed. The next update will be provided within 2 hours.

Comment: Microsoft fixed the issue and my symptoms have gone away.

Comment: Thanks a lot @kevin for the update!